# Schedule Apex Email

Tags: apex, email, email-template, opportunity

I am trying to send email to nag our agents to finsh opportunity data entry. I am running into an issue I haven't been about to work out. I am getting zero errors and sending zero emails. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Global class MarketingNag implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        List<Opportunity> ListingOps = New List<opportunity>();
        ListingOps = [select id, Agent__c, name from opportunity where agency_type__C ='seller' AND StageName ='coming soon' AND (Bedrooms__c = null OR Bedrooms__c = null OR Marketing_Description_Populated__c = false ) limit 10];
        EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'New Listing Coming Soon'];

        For(Opportunity LOPS : ListingOps){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Marketing');
            mail.setTargetObjectId(LOPS.Agent__c); 
            mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});

        }
    }
}
```

The Agent__c field is a lookup [image]

There is another field Accociate_contact_id[image]

I have tried both fields to get the agents email into the templates to address.

Comment: Have you actually scheduled this class? When does it run? Did you check the Apex Job log and see zero errors there?

Comment: I have not scheduled it yet.

Comment: So how do you expect it to send emails? Please **[edit]** your question to be more clear.

Comment: I have been running it from the developer console. MarketingNag nager = new MarketingNag();

Comment: Does that query actually return rows?

Comment: Yes this is in a sandbox so only one record exists and the soql is a match.

Comment: Did you check your email deliverability settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't run because the EmailTemplate query will always return zero rows, causing a QueryException.

DeveloperName cannot contain spaces, start with a number, or have more than one consecutive underscore.

As such, your query should look more like:

```
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'New_Listing_Coming_Soon'];
```

Secondly, never call Messaging.sendEmail in a loop. Collect all the emails into a list, then send them:

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];

    For(Opportunity LOPS : ListingOps){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Marketing');
        mail.setTargetObjectId(LOPS.Agent__c); 
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
        mails.add(mail);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```

Third, if you're emailing users, you need to set SaveAsActivity flag to false, or it will fail to send:

```
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Marketing');
        mail.setTargetObjectId(LOPS.Agent__c); 
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
        mails.add(mail);
```

Fourth, you're not checking for duplicates, so if the users are duplicated, they'll get lots of identical emails. I'd suggest creating a Set, then emailing them:

```
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    For(Opportunity LOPS : ListingOps){
        userIds.add(LOPS.Agent__c);
    }
    for(Id userId: userIds) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Marketing');
        mail.setTargetObjectId(userId); 
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
        mails.add(mail);
    }
```

Finally, based on your comments, you didn't actually call the "execute" method, so you're not actually running the code you wrote. An execute anonymous script should look like:

```
new MarketingNag().execute(null);
```

Side note: If you expect more than opportunities to possibly meet your criteria, consider removing the LIMIT or making it higher. Otherwise, you're only going to nag some of your users. Also, make sure you add a filter so you only query active users, since you can't email inactive users.

Comment: Thanks I will start nocking all these out. I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: That got me 90% email delivered content not exactly right THANK SO MUCH!

Comment: Pro tip...SingleEmailMessage has a default limit of 10 messages per sendEmail() call (may vary by org).  You WILL get an exception if you exceed your org's limit.  I use "List<List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>>" and a for() loop to send in batches of 10.

Comment: @Ixalmida Not so, see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/71761). I have successfully sent 10,000 emails in a single transaction. You are allowed 10 sendEmail calls, but the list size is not limited.