# Cannot receive more than 50 SingleEmailMessage

Tags: singleemailmessage

I use the following code to send 100 emails to one user, but received only 50 emails.

```
for(Integer i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage newMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    newMessage.setTargetObjectId('0056D000004mTR6'); //agent
    newMessage.setHtmlBody('aza<b>azaza</b>azaza');
    newMessage.setSubject('iagagago ' + i);
    newMessage.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    emailMessages.add(newMessage);
}

List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> resultList = Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);
for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result : resultList) {
    System.debug(resultList.indexOf(result) + ' '  + result.isSuccess() + ' ' + result.getErrors());
}
```

1. I cannot see any limit for it.
2. the code does not work after multiple times for one user. Is there any limit of 50 emails from Dev env or scratch org?

Note: I tested only on Dev env and scratch env. and cannot see any exceptions

**Updated**

1. after first run the Number of Records increased +100 in Email Logs - but i still received 50 emails(I tested on different temp email services)
2. when I run the second time, I did not receive any emails and Number of Records was the same in Email Logs

I think, there is some anti-spam limit of 50 emails a day from one dev/scratch env.

Comment: [Email logs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&language=en_US&type=5) should be your next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm :

> Outbound Email: Limits for Single and Mass Email Sent Using Apex
>
> ...
>
> In Developer Edition orgs and orgs evaluating Salesforce during a trial period, you can send to a maximum of 50 recipients per day, and each single email can have up to 15 recipients.

Answer (score 3):

I have literally sent myself [hundreds of emails in a single transaction](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/71761/2984). It may be that your mail system filtered some of them out, send them to spam, etc. You can try checking the Email Logs in Setup to see what happened to your emails, but there isn't any inherent limit to how many emails you can send in one transaction to users.